# Capture float in string using Ruby short-hand regex syntax

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a Ruby string which contains a dollar amount that I would like to convert into a float. I found a short hand syntax for extracting the float from the string:

```
"$123.45"[/\d+\.\d+/].to_f
# => 123.45
```

Now I realize that it does not work when there is a comma in the number:

```
"$1,023.45"[/\d+\.\d+/].to_f
# => 23.45
```

How do I change the syntax of this regex to exclude the comma while still keeping the syntax as concise as possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete the commas first using [String#delete](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-delete)

```
"$1,023.45".delete(",")[/\d+\.\d+/].to_f
#=> 1023.45
```

Comment: I didn't know about `String#delete`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
"$1,023.45".gsub(/[\$,]/, '').to_f
# => 1023.45
```

Answer (score 1):

```
p "$1,023.45".delete(",$").to_f #=> 1023.45
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex should do the job [/\d+[,.]\d+/]

[.,] means , or . may be at that position

Update: I thought you mean instead of the . like the eropeans do it. So this might not work for you. You should go for deleting the comma first to avoid  a 1,234.56 situation, like the others stated. This can not be solved with regex directly.